# Beautiful Soup and regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to identify a specific tag and its contents. The contents are html-links and I want to extract the text of these tags.

The problem is that the text is made up of different numbers according to a specific pattern. I am only interested in number such as "61993J0417" and "61991CJ0316" and I need the regexp to match both when the number has a "J" and "CJ" in the middle.

I have used this code to achieve this:

```
soup.find_all(text=re.compile('[6][1-2][0-9]{3}[J]|[CJ][0-9]{4}'))
```

The soup variable is the contents of the specific tag. This code works in 9 out of 10 cases. However, when I run this script on one of my source files, it also matches numbers such as "51987PC0716".

I cannot understand why so I turn to you for assistance.

Comment: In the specific file, this regex makes four erroneous matches: 51987PC0716, 51992PC0405, 51992PC0405-C and 51992PC0405-A09. 

If I change the regex to `'^[6][1-2][0-9]{3}[J]|[CJ][0-9]{4}$'`, it only makes two mistakes and matches 51987PC0716 and 51992PC0405.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified what the `|` applies to; by default it's the entire regex, meaning you have asked for either

```
[6][1-2][0-9]{3}[J]
```

(which is the same thing as `6[12][0-9]{3}J`) *or*

```
CJ[0-9]{4}
```

(*not* `[CJ]`, which means "either C or J").  Use parentheses to specify what the alternatives are:

```
^6[12][0-9]{3}(J|CJ)[0-9]{4}$
```

which is better written

```
^6[12][0-9]{3}C?J[0-9]{4}$
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you always have a "J" inside your string.
Therefore, make it obligatory, and make the "C" optional, using a question mark.
Something like:

```
re.compile('6[1-2][0-9]{3}C?J[0-9]{4}')
```

I have not tested this, but you probably can continue from here by yourself.